# Read page content, convert to json, enter to SQL?

Tags: jquery, sql, xml, json

I want to read the content from an external page, convert that into a predefined format, and then enter it into a database.

This is just for fun--it's taking an event list and copying the events to my own site.

Take [this](http://blog.utc.edu/TheLoop/events/) page, and manipulate it to fit a different format...

Is it possible to do this with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's possible but only to a degree**. You're going to need some server-side code to help you out. Without seeing your predefined format, it's tough to make any suggestions.

At an abstract level, I'm assuming that an event will be composed of a time, a date, and a location. From here, it would seem as if you'd need to break down the process into the following:

**Client-side**

- Find each time, date, and location.
- For each of these, you're going to want to format them into your pre-defined representation.
- Submit this data to the server.

**Server-side**

- Perform any necessary validation or processing
- Insert it into the database

Comment: It'd be easiest if you have contorl of the markup. You could create a container (like a div), assign it classname (like "event"), and then leverage jQuery's selector power to iterate through the events (think of something like $('div.event').each(function() { // grab the title, date, location, and build up a string here });

Comment: Perhaps I should start a new question that is more specific..?

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, Tom! :)

Unfortunately, I don't have control over their markup...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, up to reading, and convert to another format, but of course not into a database.

Although the html formatting on the page you given is not too good (like the use of strong within the div, instead of giving meaningful name/class/id to the item), as long as all events are in same format, it is not difficult to use JQ to convert into, whatever format you want.

Comment: Is it possible to save it as a csv file?  I need some way to get it into my database...

Maybe I could just format the output as a csv file--and then copy/paste...

Comment: As long as you know which container contains what information, any format would be possible.